# how to unnormalize a datetime field from a OLTP to a OLAP database?

Tags: datetime, plugins, transform, pentaho, kettle

Is there any plugin I might be able to inform a datetime column from a OLTP database so I can break down the date time into years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds?
Or is there a tutorial on that somewhere on the web I failed to find?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the "select values" step.
Turn your date field into a string, and set a format mask of e.g. yyyy for years.
Then do the same to get the minutes/seconds etc etc.

You can have the same field, multiple times in a select values step, and as long as you rename the field, you'll end up with multiple new fields in your stream.